# A tool to test web fonts on a live site

Tags: fonts

Are there any browser/online tools to quickly test a live site with web fonts, like Google Web Fonts? So, as I see it, I visit any site, for example, microsoft.com and click something like Analyze element in Firebug and change that font to some from Google Web Fonts list. Is there anything like that on the web?

Answer (score 4):

Try [FontFonter](http://fontfonter.com/).